# Почему не определяется значение с?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Если я "захочу" ввести интервал и введу его, то крашит с ошибкой с текстом по типу "Значение с не определено", хотя почти в начале кода я ввожу значение с даже, если пользователь не захочет этого (т.е. по умолчанию с = 1)

```
a = int(input("Введите начало счёта: "))
b = int(input("Введите конец счёта: "))
interval = input("Хотите ли Вы ввести интервал? [Y/N]: ")
if interval == "Y":
    с = int(input("Введите интервал между называемыми целыми числами: "))
else:
    c = 1
interval_1 = input("Нужно ли включать второе число в последовательность? [Y/N]: ")
if interval_1 == "Y":
    b += 1
print ("В каком формате вывести последовательность?")
format = input("Столбец - [0], Строка - [1]: ")
if format == "0":
    for i in range(a, b, c):
        print(i)
elif format == "1": 
    for i in range(a, b, c):
        print(i, end=" ")
input()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В строчке

```
с = int(input("Введите интервал между называемыми целыми числами: "))
```

`с` - русская. А нужна латинская.